# Why does Node.js show Node.js module methods and Typescript doesn't? (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I am just getting started with Typescript after spending six months with Node.js.

I have found that when importing a package, such as `string-similarity`, VSC will show all the methods of this package if I'm writing in pure Node.js, but in Typescript it won't show ANY of the methods.

The result is that I have to console.log my way through wiring up the module, whereas in pure Node.js all the methods are available to me.

### Typescript & Node.js

[image]

[image]

### Pure Node.js

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set up everything you need: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Comment: I think so. Is there a boilerplate sane "get started" config?

Comment: I have ts-node, node types, typescript all installed and working. I'm actually writing a def file for this little package but I definitely feel like its strange that vanilla Node.js can pull in more type info than Typescript is from a node package.

Answer (score 1):

When you write JavaScript code in a workspace with no `tsconfig.json` file, by default, VS Code has an "automatic type acquisition" feature that downloads the DefinitelyTyped type declarations for any modules you import.  When you write TypeScript code, by default you are expected to install the type declarations manually, in this case with `npm install @types/string-similarity`.  Alternatively, you can enable automatic type acquisition by putting the following in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "enable": true
    }
}
```

But it's considered better practice to install the declaration packages yourself so you can choose the versions you want.